# How to scroll and gone some view but there is also some view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I tried to make a layout like this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".module.activity.DetailReviewActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/videoIV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_24dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want everything in the relative layout to disappear when I scroll. Right now, the relative layout disappears only when I scroll inside the relative layout and tab layout. However, when I scroll on the view pager, the relative layout doesn't scroll. I'm not using any list view in my fragment in view pager.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `AppBarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout):

> AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to know when to scroll. The binding is done through the AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior class, meaning that you should set your scrolling view's behavior to be an instance of AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.

If the content of the `ViewPager` does not scroll then there is no "scrolling sibling." (I assume that you are saying the the `ViewPager` contents don't scroll when you say *"I'm not using any list view".*)

If the `ViewPager` contents do not scroll, then you could wrap the contents of the `ViewPager` in a `NestedScrollView` something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your ViewPager content layout here. -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is what would be added to the `ViewPager`.

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama Updated answer.

Comment: it works but every fragment in view pager gone background included